# Javascript: Unable to access response object and dynamically generated html elements outside the function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am creating a todo app with Django + Ajax. On load I am loading all the tasks from the db and displaying it and when user clicks on any task i want to mark it as completed. The problems i am facing are

1. I am unable to access the dynamically generated html elements and
   the response object, outside the buildList() function.
2. When i add event listener to a task (span element with class = title) i am unable to access the task object so i can send it to backend using ajax request and work with it.

todo.js

```
buildList()

function buildList(){
    var wrapper = document.querySelector("#list-wrapper")
    wrapper.innerHTML = ''
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task-list/', true)
    xhr.onload  = function(){
        if(this.status==200){
            var list = JSON.parse(this.response)
            for (var i in list){
                var item = `
                    <div id="data-row-${i}", class="task-wrapper flex-wrapper">
                        <div style="flex:7">
                            <span class="title">${list[i].title}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div style="flex:1">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info edit">Edit</button>
                        </div> 
                        <div style="flex:1">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark delete">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `
                wrapper.innerHTML += item
            }

            for(i in list){
                var tasks = document.querySelectorAll('.title')
                tasks.forEach(function(el, list){
                    el.addEventListener('click',()=>{
                        console.log(list[i])
                    })
                })


            }
        }
    }
    xhr.send()
}

// Addding a Task //
var form = document.querySelector("form")
form.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        var title = document.getElementById('title').value
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task-create/', true)
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json')
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken',csrftoken)
        xhr.onload = function(){
            if(this.status==200){
                buildList() 
                document.getElementById('form').reset()
            }
        }
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"title":title}))
    }
)

// Marking a task as complete //
function taskComplete(e){
    console.log(e.target)
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
    <title>To Do</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div id="task-container">
            <div id="form-wrapper">
                <form id="form">
                    <div class="flex-wrapper">
                        <div style="flex: 6">
                            <input id="title" class="form-control" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Add task">
                        </div>
                        <div style="flex: 1">
                            <input id="submit" class="btn" type="submit" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
             </div>

            <div id="list-wrapper">

            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="{% static 'todo.js' %}"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when you add the event listener you want to access a variable named `list` with your fetched data, however in that lexical scope `list` is being assigned to a callback argument. My suggestion is to rename the callback argument. Then you can access `list` from the parent scope.

```
 tasks.forEach(function(el, index){
```